# how can I handle my python errors in node server (HeartBeat)

Tags: python, node.js, error-handling, socket.io

my Nodejs server with python scripts are combined via socket.io

I can run my python scripts and call its functions it works well until I send correct data.

the problem is when the python functions got error I can not handle them in node js
I want to understand before the python Scripts crashed I don't run them
I hope could explain the problem fluently

**JS**

```js
function startScripts() {
    let child = spawn('python', ['-u', __dirname + '/pyScripts/' + 'config.py']);

    sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
        socket.join('config');

        socks = socket;
    });

    child.stderr.on('data', function (err) {
        console.log(err.toString());
    });

    child.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log(data.toString());
    });
}


function runPyFunction(data, callback) {

    sockets.to('config').emit('run', data);

    const handleResponse = (res) => {
        if (res) {
            return callback({ 'message': res, 'status': 'ok' }, null);
        }
        else {
            return callback(null, { 'message': 'Function or file is not found', 'status': 'failed' });
        }
    };

    socks.removeAllListeners();

    socks.on('response', handleResponse);
}




app.post('/py', (req, res) => {

    let data = req.body;

    let userData = {
        'filename': 'test',

        'function': 'multiplication',
        'args':[3]

    }

    runPyFunction(userData, (res2, err) => {
        if (res) {
            console.log('here is message');
            console.log(res);
            res.end(JSON.stringify(res2))
        } else {

            console.log('here is error');
         console.log(err);
        }
    })

})
```

**Python** **Config.py**

```
def run_function(data):
for module in globals():
    if data['filename'] == module:
        for function in getmembers(globals()[module], isfunction):
            if data['function'] == function[0]:
                print(data)
                if 'args' in data:
                    return sio.emit('response', function[1](*data['args']))
                else:
                    return sio.emit('response', function[1]())

# Emit false if function or file not found
return sio.emit('response', False)
```

**test.py**

```
import os

 def multiplication(number):
 return number*number*number
```

Problem is : how to handle Errors when python scipts Die or crash ?

on the Code Above I made a communication between node js and py scipts
I added an API '/py' I send data to it (here is Mock data) and I tell I want to execute this File.py and this function name with these args

it searches to find the exact function.
it works fine; the problem is for example on the code above I must give int variable to py function when I send String data it downs and I can not handle it with my controller in node js.

how can I understand py Errors in node js ?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please provide relevant code changes you have and the errors you see with them.

Comment: Provide more information, show a bit of your code if possible, share what exactly you did, what you received, and what you were expecting to see with code samples?

Comment: let me explain more I added my Codes Just see them I will add my explanations there